# Add a fixed content just below the clicked card

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I am showing a dynamic set of cards using the display: grid; Now on clicking a particular card, its extra information should be shown just below the clicked card. I have achieved showing extra information below but stuck with positioning it in the center of the window. The extra information div should take full window width(not the width of the card and shouldn't be an overlay) but should be below the clicked card like the image. I tried the following but extra information div is taking its starting position from where the clicked card starts. It is going out of the window for the 4th card.

html:

```
<div class="cards-list">
   <div class="card-list__item" (click)="cardClicked(item)" *ngFor="let item of cardItems; 
    let i = index" [index]="i">
       <div>{{item.name}}
       <div class="extra-info">Extra Information<div>
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.cards-list{
     display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1.4rem;
    z-index: 2;
    &__item{
       position:relative;
       .extra-info{
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          width: 100vw;
          top: 102%;
          z-index: 100;
          background-color: skyblue;
          min-height: 20rem;
        }
    }
}
```

The layout should look like this:

[image]

Can we achieve this by modifying the given CSS or do we have so some calculations to find get the position? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey there, please fix the link on your post, the image there doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include the rendered HTML and compiled CSS. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).